# Joomla complicate menu system

Tags: joomla, menu

I'm looking at building a site for a client and wondered if Joomla is even up to the task.

Amongst other functions on the site I have a need to display products in two different ways.

Each product has a brand and a type so, for example, a particular laptop might be brand=Acer, type=Laptop.  Clearly this will be database driven.

I want the menu system to show the products in different ways; 2 top level menu items would show...

*types within brands, eg...*

Acer

- Laptops
- ...

*brands within types, eg...*

Laptops

- Acer
- ...

Each lower level link would show a list of the appropriate matching items.

Is this even possible or am I more in the realms of needing to do it all myself and forget Joomla?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that asking if I'm up to the task is really that helpful.  I can assure you that I am, but the question is am I going to spend several weeks delving into the innards of how to make Joomla work for me or simply write a custom system myself.  I'd hope that experienced folks here would provide helpful answers to a 'real world' (i.e. commercial world) question.

Comment: WHy would you need to delve into the innards? It would take you about an hour to set that up with tags or with a combination of categories and tags, it is just a standard way of working with joomla nothing fancy.

Comment: By all means DO use Joomla or another framework, do not even think to build something from scratch.  It will be faster to learn how to use / develop on Joomla and adapt one of the dozens of e-commerce solutions than to build a system of your own.  And maintenance costs will be a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

The stadard menu system does not provide such function. But I you should have a look at 3rd party extension such as virtueMart (webshop for joomla) or SOBI (directory-system for joomla). They might give you what you need.

Comment: thanks for the pointers...I've been looking at VirtueMart which seems to give me the organisation structure (multipl categories) that I need, but I need to see how to use these to drive a menu system.

Not yet looked at SOBI.

Comment: Why woudn't you just use tags?